# How can I close a file mid process without losing data?

Tags: c, file-io

I am running a process and I realized it will take longer than I thought to finish. It has been running for quite some time now and I would like to end the process without losing the data it has generated. The file outputs to a text file using C. How can I close the file mid process without losing data?

Comment: More important perhaps, is how you re-open it later to continue without loss of data, which should be with the `"a"` mode. In the first place, if the file does not exist it is created. If it does exist it is opened for appending.

Comment: Copy the text file and save it somewhere else, then end the process.

Comment: @Rob That's extremely unlikely to help.

Comment: It's printing from a script, but I open the file with "w". The text file is empty if I try to open it.

Comment: Are you asking about a program you've written, and that you'd like to make more robust against interruption the next time you run it?  Or are you asking about a program that's running now?  If the program is running now, I don't think there's anything you can do.  If it's a program you're trying to fix to work better next time, do one or both of (1) call `fflush()` periodically and (2) catch SIGINT and SIGTERM and in thme do any cleanup you need and then call `exit()`.

Comment: what's the operating system?

Comment: It is running now, but I think my computation time will end before it's done. I will take your advice and add those lines. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Ahmed Masud, it's a script submitted through a Unix shell. Script is in C and compiled using gcc.

Comment: Is it under Linux or something else? I ask because it may change the way you get the file descriptor of the open file that you want to "save" so to speak. :-)

Comment: I believe it is Linux, but I'm actually not 100% sure. I can only access the output files using the Terminal.

Comment: @AhmedMasud What are you considering? There's nothing you can do from outside the process to force the program to flush its buffer. Why would the FD be useful?

Comment: @Barmar in case of emergency :) you can actually just stop the process attach a debugger, and make your FILE * unbuffered and use the file descriptor to figure out which FP it is, then you can make the corresponding FILE * unbuffered by injecting a sevbuf (incase of stdio) ... let the next write instruction happen and verify that you have "enough output"... stop the process copy the file to another ... and kill the process

Comment: @Barmar in case of file descriptor (i.e. no stdio being used) you can use the file descriptor directly and call fsync(2) ... the data is definitely sent to the disk cache. so it will be readable.

Comment: @AhmedMasud If the file isn't buffered, you don't need to do anything. The data is safely in the kernel buffers, killing the process won't harm it.

Comment: Attaching a debugger depends on the program being compiled with debugging symbols.

Comment: @bamar errr no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up canceling the computation and took Steve Summit's advice which was to catch SIGINT and SIGTERM as well as calling fflush() periodically. I was actually able to recover some data, but at least now, I can recover all the data that has been processed.

Comment: Depending on whether streams or descriptors are used, that might be `fsync`.